# Feature Summary using Rollup-

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I am trying to modify a rollup query I found to use a select statement instead of a view. the rollup is:

```
select case when (grouping(lut_XXX_type_name) = 1) then 'ALL'
    else ISNULL(lut_XXX_type_name, 'unknown')
    end as lut_XXX_type_name,
    case when (GROUPING(lut_YYY_status_name) = 1)then 'ALL'
        ELSE ISNULL(lut_YYY_status_name, 'UNKNOWN')
        end as lut_YYY_status_name,
        SUM (ZZZ_quantity) as qtySum
    from database.dbo.View_permitted
    group by lut_XXX_type_name,lut_YYY_status_name with rollup
```

I want to replace the 'from database.dbo.View_permitted' with the following so I put it in Parenthesis:

```
SELECT      dbo.WWW.WWW_id, dbo.WWW.WWW_grantee, dbo.YYY_entity.YYY_entity_apn, dbo.lut_YYY_status.lut_YYY_status_name, 
                      dbo.lut_entity_type.lut_entity_type_name, dbo.lut_XXX_type.lut_XXX_type_name, dbo.county.county_name, dbo.ZZZ.ZZZ_quantity, 
                      dbo.YYY.YYY_city, dbo.YYY.YYY_term, dbo.YYY.YYY_date_executed
FROM         dbo.WWW INNER JOIN
                      dbo.YYY ON dbo.WWW.WWW_id = dbo.YYY.YYY_WWW_id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.lut_YYY_status ON dbo.YYY.YYY_lut_YYY_status_id = dbo.lut_YYY_status.lut_YYY_status_id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ZZZ ON dbo.WWW.WWW_id = dbo.ZZZ.ZZZ_WWW_id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.lut_XXX_type ON dbo.ZZZ.ZZZ_lut_XXX_type_id = dbo.lut_XXX_type.lut_XXX_type_id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.YYY_entity ON dbo.YYY.YYY_id = dbo.YYY_entity.YYY_entity_YYY_id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.lut_entity_type ON dbo.YYY_entity.YYY_entity_lut_entity_type_id = dbo.lut_entity_type.lut_entity_type_id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.county ON dbo.WWW.WWW_county_id = dbo.county.county_id
WHERE     (dbo.ZZZ.ZZZ_lut_XXX_type_id IN (20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 65, 66)) AND (dbo.county.county_name IN ('County1', 'county2')) AND 
                      (dbo.YYY_entity.YYY_entity_WWW <> 0) AND (dbo.lut_YYY_status.lut_YYY_status_name IN ('Active', 'permitted’))
```

when I execute, I get the following error:

```
   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
```

I have read threads regarding use of semicolon, I modified the end to be:

```
group by rollup(lut_XXX_type_name,lut_YYY_status_name)
```

but it is still not working...

Thanks for your help-

Comment: Your sample query has no `with`, so I don't see how that error could be generated.

Comment: at the end there is the 'with rollup'

Comment: did you add an alias after your parens?  So you go from `from view as v` to `from (sql) as v`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
group by rollup(lut_XXXXX_type_name, lut_YYYYY_status_name)
```

`with rollup` is used in some other databases.

Comment: and all the field names are underlined like it doesn't know what the table is?

Comment: @Gross . . . If it doesn't recognize `group` then something is wrong further up the query.

Comment: I am replacing the from DATABASE1.dbo.VIEW_ActivePermittedPending